# Does TASS have a disclosed direct line with the Kremlin?

Tags: russian-federation, media

It's been [disclosed](https://www.dw.com/en/why-deutsche-welle-is-not-the-same-as-rt/a-60666432) that RT has a direct line with the Kremlin.

> When Time magazine's Moscow correspondent Simon Shuster visited RT Editor-in-Chief Margareta Simonyan in her office in 2015, he noticed an old-fashioned yellow telephone on her desk. It was her secure line directly to the Kremlin, Simonyan admitted to Shuster, "to discuss secret things." She has been RT's editor-in-chief since its inception in 2005.

I'm curious however if that's because of the high-profile of RT.

> In an interview with Russian daily Kommersant in 2012, Simonyan said she saw RT as part of an information war with the Western world, and compared the broadcaster's role to that of the Defense Ministry.
>
> "The Defense Ministry was fighting with Georgia, but we were conducting the information war, and what's more, against the whole Western world," she said. "It's impossible to start making a weapon only when the war has already started! That's why the Defense Ministry isn't fighting anyone at the moment, but it's ready for defense. So are we."
>
> In 2013, Russian President Vladimir Putin declared that RT "cannot but reflect the official position of the Russian government on events in our country and the rest of the world."

Does e.g. TASS have a similar direct line with the Kremlin?

Comment: With direct line you mean simply lots of direct communications. Emails or text messages would work too. Or you really mean a physical telephone?

Comment: @Trilarion: something overt like for RT. (It makes sense to ask since TASS is also state-owned.)

Comment: Discussed on Meta: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6215/28554

Comment: Of course. What do you expect from the official press agency of the Russian Federation?